# SSIS Script Task Fails when run from SQL Agent Works fine if run individually

Tags: .net, ssis, script-task

[image]I have a scheduled project running by sql server agent. It contains multiple packages. One of the package contains the script task which is calling my api deployed on azure. This whole process runs on a virtual machine.

Whenever that process runs from agent as per the schedule, it throws an error(exception has been thrown by the target method of invocation) as shown in screenshot. But if I run that process manually in VS it works fine(Also if I run specific package from IS catalogs, it works fine). I have tried to put log on the last statement of my api. It worked fine. It executed till the last statement without any issue.

I went through many links similar to [SSIS Script Task Fails when run from SQL Agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqdHO.png) but did not reach to the solution.

Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no screenshot. And besides... please take the time to put the error text in your question so it's searchable. Besides that, please look in the SSIS logs for more detail

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Added the screenshot and error text.

Comment: Temporarily change the SQL Agent service account to a local admin and see if that fixes the issue. If it does fix, the issue, then you need to narrow down and work out where the security issue is. For example, script tasks need write access to `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP` in order to run

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have tried to do it by changing agent's account to the local admin but didn't work. Showing same error message. Let me know if you have any other suggestion.

Comment: At this stage it would help to see the code. Are you referring to drives in your script task? They may not exist on the SQL Server - remember when it's run in a job it is on the SQL Server.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am just referring an API in which it executes some logging operations on some other database. As I mentioned everything works fine if I execute that single package from IS catalogs manually.

Comment: Is the sql server on a different server to where you edit your packages?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No it's the same server on VM.

Comment: You're going to have to add line by line logging to your script task to see which line it fails on. You could also try running it as _you_ in SQL Agent

Answer (score 0):

After spending so much hours in understanding the issue, I have reached to the solution to my own problem. 
There are some limitations over the use of script tasks in SSIS. The API I was calling from it takes too much time that pushes the script task to end the async thread execution. After which it was returning failed status. (This issue was not occurring in debug mode.)
Then I tried to use the sync method by using **HttpClientConnection** but it's major limitation is timeout limit. We can set maximum of 5 minutes for any call.

Finally I have split that API into multiple tasks to remove the timeouts which solved my issue. Thanks.